# React js : setState object to setup button's style and options

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React, and I couldn't figure out why vscode is telling me there is an error.
I made a function component, and within it, I set up initial values for a button as an object using useState hook as the following,

```
const [loginButtonSetting, setLoginButtonSetting] = useState({buttonColor: "#acd036", isButtonActive: true,});
```

and within the component's return value, the button's attributes are written like the following,

```
<button style={{ backgroundColor: { loginButtonSetting.buttonColor} }} disabled={loginButtonSetting.isButtonActive}>Button</button>
```

for this button, I think the initial value for the button color should be #acd036 and disabled option should be true. But vscode is kept on putting the wriggly underline at "loginButtonSetting" of backgroundColor, saying it's a "parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ','".

Things I have tried:

1. putting bracket around loginButtonSetting.buttonColor.
2. using spread operator :   [...loginButtonSetting, buttonColor]  I knew this wouldn't work though

Please help out if you know what is going on! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need extra curly brackets when inside the style object to put the buttonColor, it's because inside object you can put JS directly (here using buttonColor property).

```
<button style={{ backgroundColor: loginButtonSetting.buttonColor }} disabled={loginButtonSetting.isButtonActive}>Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set `backgroundColor` as:

[`STACKBLITZ LINK`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6lp92w?file=src%2FApp.js)

```
<button
        style={{ backgroundColor: loginButtonSetting.buttonColor }}
        disabled={loginButtonSetting.isButtonActive}
      >
        Button
      </button>
```

What you are setting is:

```
backgroundColor: { loginButtonSetting.buttonColor}
```

`backgroundColor` should be a value not an object

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the value for the backgroundColor as string literals with back ticks:
<button style={{ backgroundColor: '${loginButtonSetting.buttonColor}' }} disabled={loginButtonSetting.isButtonActive}>Button